How to find lines with specific character in a row and replace them with one line?
I have a large patch (over 80k lines) and in this patch I want to remove the lines containing plus and leave only one line.
For example:
+$as_echo "$CC_FOR_BUILD" >&6; }
+
+
+
+
+case `pwd` in
+  *\ * | *\    *)
+    { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in \`pwd\`" >&5
+$as_echo "$as_me: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in \`pwd\`" >&2;} ;;
+esac
+
+
+
+macro_version='2.4.2'
+macro_revision='1.3337'
+
+
+
+
+
+
+
+
+
+ltmain="$ac_aux_dir/ltmain.sh"

To make it look like this afterwards:
+$as_echo "$CC_FOR_BUILD" >&6; }
+
+case `pwd` in
+  *\ * | *\    *)
+    { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in \`pwd\`" >&5
+$as_echo "$as_me: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in \`pwd\`" >&2;} ;;
+esac
+
+macro_version='2.4.2'
+macro_revision='1.3337'
+
+ltmain="$ac_aux_dir/ltmain.sh"

Using vim, sed or awk. Maybe some other tool.
UPD: uniq is not suitable because in such a large patch it can remove not only strings starting with a plus character

Yes, absolutely. What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

For this particular case, uniq filename would work.

@TedLyngmo Unfortunately, uniq has removed other lines

@amkgi As I said, for the particular case you've shown in the question, it does what you want and the result is what you've shown you want to have afterwards.

awk '/^+$/ && no==0 {no=1; print} !/^+$/ {no=0; print}' may give a better result if other lines may be repeated though

awk '!(p=="+" && $0==p); {p=$0}' file

Perhaps sed -n 'N;/^+\n+$/!P;D' file? BTW uniq might remove false positives!

@potong As I said previously, uniq works and produces the expected output for the input presented in the question. If the input contains  repeated lines other than + it will not work.

With dos2unix (because your file contains carriage returns) and awk:
dos2unix < your_file \
| awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""}
       {
         s=1;
         for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
           if($i=="+" && s<2){print $i; s++}
           if($i!="+")       {print $i; s=1}
         }
       }'


See: 8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR

I solved this issue using the next method. I repeated (@:) this command %s/^+\n^+\n^+$/+ in Vim editor until the pattern was no longer found. I guess it's not a good solution, but in some places in the patch I realised that I should also keep two lines instead of one.
That said, in the comments to the question itself, I think Ted Lyngmo gave exactly the right reply to my question.

You should ask a new question with your real requirements and show that vim snippet as your attempted solution.
